# How to make a ImageView link to a specified phone Number?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Can anyone help me in that question? I want to make a simple link in a ImageView to a specified phone Number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an onClickListener for the ImageView, and have it do whatever you want.  In this case, launch an intent to make a call.

Comment: more easily , use imageButton and set onclickListener on button. its the properway. and call your number in onclick method of listener.

Comment: THe difference between imageButton and an ImageView is in looks.  ImageButton looks like a button.  Sometimes that's what you want, and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: not necessarily, by setting background property and by setting scale type property, you can even show image button just like image view. and there are other possible ways of showing imagebutton just like image view,

Comment: Yes, but if you just want a clickable image, you can just use an image view, or you can use an image button and remember to set 3 or 4 properties.  I'm going with the simpler way.  Now if I actually want it to look like a button (which sometimes is the case, say for an action bar), then its a great class to have.

Comment: its genuinely your own choice, else its possible both ways. Cheers!